# User Login Control

Tags: ios, user-interface

I am just trying to figure out the best way to handle this. What I want is a User Login Control that once the user logs in, brings them directly to their "user management" area. But if the user closes the app, it makes them log back in. I want them to close the app and have it go directly to the user management page.

Is there a framework or API I can use to help me accomplish what I need? If not, what is the best way to handle this? For right now I am using SOAP with encryption to handle the login connection. Should I store the username and password and reconnect every time the app is launched?

Answer (score 0):

For encrypted data, storing usernames and passwords in the Keychain is your safest bet.  Reconnection could then be established by gathering the values from the keychain and performing another SOAP request.

The keychain documentation and API is confusing, I'll admit, but it is the most secure place on the phone.  Luckily, there are quite a few [tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) on the subject.